# Jenkins checking out correct branch

Tags: jenkins, jobs

I am using Jenkins, to deploy war to tomcat. Created a Maven Project job, we changed on pom.xml. Have 2 issues:

1. first thing Jenkins is always checking out from master, whereas I would want to checkout from feature. I gave origin/feature/sprint1.
2. Deploying is failing.

any advice, please help.

Thanks!

Comment: please update your question with error *stacktrace*. are using `svn`or `git`?

Comment: Git plugin in jenkins have branch option from which repository to fetch!!